# append to .txt file with specific pattern

Tags: bash, perl, parsing, awk, grep

I have a .txt file with 1 word written in [leet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)
the word is "`arhie`" letters are dividet by "`,`"

```
4,1²,#,!,&    //a=4,r=1²,h=#,i=!,e=&
@,2,(-),1,€   //a=@,r=2,h=(-),i=1,e=€
/\,?,)-(,|,£  //a=/\,r=?,h=)-(,i=|,e=£
```

I need to append to this wordlist the word "`rarh`" with the same pattern

Example of output:

```
4,1²,#,!,&,1²,4,1²,#     // a=4,r=1²,h=#,i=!,e=&
@,2,(-),1,€,2,@,2,(-)    // a=@,r=2,h=(-),i=1,e=€
/\,?,)-(,|,£,?,/\,?,)-(  // a=/\,r=?,h=)-(,i=|,e=£
```

I know that perl awk or grep can be used for parsing the words, but have no idea how.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS="," } { a=$1;r=$2;h=$3;i=$4;e=$5; print a,r,h,i,e,r,a,r,h }' <<< '4,1²,#,!,&
@,2,(-),1,€
/\,?,)-(,|,£'
4,1²,#,!,&,1²,4,1²,#
@,2,(-),1,€,2,@,2,(-)
/\,?,)-(,|,£,?,/\,?,)-(
```

Comment: Can you please comment how can I use that script, I am new to awk. Thank you!

Comment: Redirect the input file to stdin, and get the output file from stdout.

Comment: I am sorry still don't get it. I have a file.txt how can I from terminal execute your code, that will affect that file?

Comment: It won't. `awk ... < file.txt > output.txt`